# Background Color Penetrates Solid Object in Eevee as if Transparent

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, eevee-render-engine

I've been trying to do an interior scene in Eevee and can't figure out why blender is treating an object with thickness and subdivisions as if its entirely transparent

*Screenshot of material settings*
[image: Screenshot of material settings]

*The scene inside of the object with Eevee.*
[image]

*The scene inside of the object with Cycles*
[image]

*The scene outside of the object*
[image]

Comment: What is the roughness value of the material? Low roughness values will cause the material to be reflective, thus having its colour heavily affected by the environment.

Comment: I just turned the roughness right up to 1 and its still behaving as if its transparent, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Could you upload the file to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ? Or just screenshot the material values then.

Comment: It honestly doesn't look transparent to me.

Comment: I just updated my original post with the material settings, its just the default principled settings. @Nate_Sycro27 it might not be, but I was expecting the inside to be dark and then I'd have to create openings to bring light in